# created "div" with document.createElement("div"); multiplies in each call

Tags: javascript, createelement

I create a function "getInfoProduits()" whose role is to get products information and to display them. To do this, it creates "div" using "document.createElement("div");", that will contain products information. But the problem is that these div multiplies each call to this function, each time I click on the button who calls this function. It's totally logical but I still have no solution yet.
This is th function:

```
function getInfoProduits()
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(i<idProduits.length)
        {
            request.open("GET","http://patisserie-orient.fr/prestashop/prestashop/api/products/"+idProduits[i]+"?PHP_AUTH_USER="+PHP_AUTH_USER+"&ws_key="+ws_key,true);

            request.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if(request.readyState==4)
                    {
                        //alert("Status2 is  "+request.status);
                        if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0)
                        {
                            response1  = request.responseXML.documentElement;
                            nameProduits[i] = response1.getElementsByTagName('name')[0].getElementsByTagName('language')[0].firstChild.data;
                                                            priceProduits[i] = response1.getElementsByTagName('price')[0].firstChild.data+" €";
                                                            descriptionProduits[i] = response1.getElementsByTagName('description_short')[0].getElementsByTagName('language')[0].firstChild.data;
                                                            quantitieProduitsDisponible[i] = response1.getElementsByTagName('quantity')[0].firstChild.data;
                                                            idImageProduits[i] = response1.getElementsByTagName('image')[0].getElementsByTagName('id')[0].firstChild.data;


                            maDiv = document.createElement("div");
                            maDiv.id = 'id_de_la_div'+i;

                            malabel = document.createElement("div");
                            malabel1 = document.createElement("div");



                            malabel.innerHTML=nameProduits[i];
                            malabel1.innerHTML=priceProduits[i];


                                                            maDiv.innerHTML='<img src='+url+'  width="50" height="50" align="right">';

                            maDiv.className="ui-bar ui-bar-e cadre";
                            document.getElementById("divbar").appendChild(maDiv);                           
                            document.getElementById('id_de_la_div'+i).appendChild(malabel);
                            document.getElementById('id_de_la_div'+i).appendChild(malabel1);


                            maDivvide = document.createElement("div");
                            maDivvide.innerHTML='<br>';
                            document.getElementById("divbar").appendChild(maDivvide);
                            i++;
                             getInfoProduits1();
                         }
                     }
                }

            request.send();

        }   
    else
        {
            return;
        }

}
```

Comment: Just make the div in your html code, then edit the content of it in your function..

Comment: i don't understand. Multiply how? how many times do they multiply? if you call the createElement multiple times then it will be created multiple times. Can you explain further?

Comment: yes @ Rob i have a div "divbar" in my html code, and in this function i edit it with adding new label and div containing product information

Comment: @Th0rbdike when I calla this function, createElement is executed, so a new div is created in each call, but I want that the div will b created just in th first call to the function

Comment: trx to check if anything happens by debugging with your console. Add console.log(<your action>); and see what happens and find the bug!

Answer (score 0):

"Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element." Seems to be what you need!

[jQuery .one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

There is also a pure JS solution

```
fnname = (function(){
    var counter = 0; 
    return function(param1, param2, ...) {
        if (counter > 0) {
            return;
        }
        counter++;

        // your normal function code here   };
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use this with my function?

Comment: If you don't know this, you should read a little bit more about JavaScript. I would recommend [W3shools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

Comment: You implement this function, pass the parameters needed, than execute the function at the place you need it.

Comment: You can access it than by fnname(params).

Comment: The function was not well indented, that's why I haven't understood it.